# Do while loops reset the variable in Python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, tic-tac-toe

I'm new to Python, and I was following a youtube tutorial on how to make a tic-tac-toe. My code works fine, but I can't seem to understand why one section of the code works. Here's the code:

```
print(player + "'s turn.")
position = input("Choose a position from 1-9: ")

valid = False
while not valid:
    while position not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
        position = input("Choose a position from 1-9: ")

    position = int(position) - 1

    if board[position] == "-":
        valid = True
    else:
        print("You can't go there. Go again.")
```

Basically, this code accepts an input from the player between 1 to 9 (which are the 9 positions in the tictactoe). It runs a while loop in order to check if it is between 1-9, and check if the player is placing their Os or Xs in a blank(-) spot. If it is not a blank, the code repeats itself.

Here's an example of what shows up when I input 8

```
- | - | -
- | - | -
- | - | -
X's turn.
Choose a position from 1-9: 8
- | - | -
- | - | -
- | X | -
O's turn.
Choose a position from 1-9:
```

Ok, I will input another 8 so it would overlap the previous X

```
You can't go there. Go again.
Choose a position from 1-9:
```

However, what I can't understand is why the "position"(when it has a value between 1-9) runs the inner while loop(the one with the string list) and asks for another input. If position is a number that is between 1-9 and was just accidently placed in a non-blank space, shouldn't the inner while loop not be triggered, since it is between 1-9? I think this should just go on in an endless loop (of the outer while loop) as the position keeps subtracting itself by 1 until it is stopped by the inner while loop when it goes below "1".

Can you guys please explain why the inner while loop works and asks for an input when the position(between 1 and 9) does not meet the inner loop's conditions?

Edited:
Here is how the board looks like as one of you asked:

```
    # Game Board
board = ["-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-"]

# Display board
def display_board():
    print(f'{board[0]} | {board[1]} | {board[2]}')
    print(f'{board[3]} | {board[4]} | {board[5]}')
    print(f'{board[6]} | {board[7]} | {board[8]}')
```

Comment: What does `board` look like?

Comment: I added it above for your reference.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your posted code fails due to at least one indentation error.  Your posted program hangs waiting for input.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Explain this code block to me" is not a Stack Overflow issue.

Comment: Most of all, please explain *exactly* what you don't understand from the output you get when you trace this code. Include that trace in your MRE.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this stackoverflow. I edited it, so hopefully everyone knows what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it works is because input() returns a string, and the if statement checks if the string input is contained in that list of strings.("8" is in ["8"]). However, after the input is given it's converted into an int and an int can't be equal to a string so it asks for another input.
in this case:

```
position="8"
position = int("8")-1 = 8-1 = 7
...
if 7 not in ["1",.."9"]: #And it isn't
    #ask for another input
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your time to look at this issue!

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the datatype of the variable position. The code is quite confusing because it keeps changing from str to int and vice versa repeatedly. When you try to re-enter 8 as input for O's turn, it enters the outer loop, changes from '8' to 7(int). It reaches the else block and prints the error message. The variable 'valid' is still False and we go to the next iteration of the outer loop. Crucially, the datatype **is still int** and an int value *will not be* 'in' a list consisting of string elements, and therefore we can enter the inner loop where the player is prompted for a new input.

In my opinion, it would be better to just leave *position* as an int variable.

Comment: Thx a lot for your time to look at this issue!